# How to get data from a separate collection and join it with a user collection without having a same common id to link both of them in MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have 2 collections in MongoDB namely "users" and "dictionaries".
I'm building a simple dictionary (simple form and table) where the users can store any words that they have learned.
I have also built authentication for the web app so only registered users have access to the dictionary table.

My problem is I don't know how to link both of the collections because I don't have a common 
property to do a lookup function. What I would like to do is basically whenever a user logs in, his/her data from the dictionary collection will be rendered in the table.

Do I need to create a common property/id in both collections (that would be redundant no?)?

The User and Dictionary schema are as below; ( The _id should be automatically created in both collections but I think both ids are not the same)

```
    const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
      joindate: {
        type: Date,
      },
      fullname: {
        type: String,
      },
      email: {
        type: String,
      },
      password: {
        type: String,
      },
      dateofbirth: {
        type: Date,
      },
    });

  const dictionarySchema = mongoose.Schema({
  word: {
    type: String,
  },
  meaning: {
    type: String,
  },
  example: {
    type: String,
  },
  language: {
    type: String,
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
  },
});
```

Comment: Of you dont' keep anything to reference the relationship, how can you tell the owner of a word, or which words a particular user owns?

Answer (score 1):

You can link in 2 ways

1. Either you store references to the Dictionary model in the User model as an array of references.Then you will be able to fetch the user along with his dictionaries

`dictionaries: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: '<Name of Dictionary model>' }]`

You can then fetch the dictionaries with the users using populate

`UserModel.find({}).populate(‘dictionaries’).exec()`

You can find examples in the mongoose documentation
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

2. You can store a reference in the Dictionary model as a new field, for eg. creator

`creator: { type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: <Name of User Model> }`

You can then query your Dictionary model to find by creator

`DictionaryModel.find({creator: ObjectId(<ObjectId of User>)})`

Or if you don't want to link, you can store the dictionaries directly as an array field in your user model

Comment: But both ObjectIds from the User and Dictionary Models are different (One created during sign up and one created when user submit data to dictionary table). How does it know to correspond to the correct user? By putting the ref to the property will it link correctly?

Comment: If you follow the first approach, you have to add the dictionary ObjectId to the dictionaries array of the User who created it every time that user creates a new dictionary.
And if you use the second approach you have to add the ObjectId of the User who is creating the dictionary in the creator field of the Dictionary whenever a new Dictionary is created

Answer (score 0):

You have your own answer, yes, you need to create a common field/id, which will help us to map each users to their saved words.

If you are worried about storing the common field/id twice in DB, then, you can go with something similar schema like below:

```
userSchema = {
  joindate:,
  fullname:,
  email:,
  password:,
  dateofbirth:
  dictionaries: [{
    word:,
    meaning:,
    example:,
    language:,
    date:,
  }]
}
```

The `users` collection will be having the `dictionaries` field, where you can push all the words stored by that particular user. And you don't need to do any `lookup`. As MongoDB is a NoSQL DB, there is no relation at all. You are a free bird.

**Update:**
What I meant by common field is that, something like `username` or `userId`. I believe that only logged in user can store the words. Then you can take the logged in user's username, and store it along with other details of words, in `dictionaries` collection. So, the updated Schema will look like below:

```js
const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
  },
  joindate: {
    type: Date,
  },
  fullname: {
    type: String,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
  },
  dateofbirth: {
    type: Date,
  },
});

const dictionarySchema = mongoose.Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
  },
  word: {
    type: String,
  },
  meaning: {
    type: String,
  },
  example: {
    type: String,
  },
  language: {
    type: String,
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
  },
});
```

Comment: How do I make sure that the ids are the same because both ObjectIds are created with unique ids (2 separated forms - signup and add dictionary data)? I can manually create a custom field for the id in the form but that would be an additional entry for the user to fill in which is not user-friendly.